# SQL Server creating folders

Tags: sql, sql-server, directory

I just want to know if what I am thinking can be done somehow in SQL. I have members in my database, I want to create folders for each member based on the member name, is this possible? If yes, may I see an example if possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Of course it is possible. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Folders? What kind of folders?

Comment: My guess : Windows explorer

Comment: Just regular folder, I use windows so for example folders on my desktop with all the user names.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible but you will have to use a CLR user defined function which means you have to write a code to create a folder in a .NET language (that's easy), build and assembly and create a function in SQL Server from this assembly.

See more in here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k(v=vs.90).aspx